# Azure AD V2 app login using Microsoft account

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory

I am using Azure AD V2 app for authentication into my app based on Angular. I am using ASP.NET Web APIs for backend.

I am using auth code flow to get the auth code and using which I am fetching the user access token and refresh token as mentioned in the article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow

This flow works fine for me with Azure AD accounts. When I login using outlook account it provides me the code but when I try to get access token using code it doesn't work and I get Bad Request error in the response.

Following is the I am using in the Web API:

```
        public async Task<string> GetAccessToken(string code)
        {
            string token = "", refresh_token = "";            

            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            var keyValuePairs = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
            keyValuePairs.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("scope", AppsConfiguration.idaScope));
            keyValuePairs.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", AppsConfiguration.idaClient_id));
            keyValuePairs.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", AppsConfiguration.idaClient_secret));
            keyValuePairs.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", AppsConfiguration.grant_type_authorization_code));
            keyValuePairs.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("code", code));
            keyValuePairs.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("redirect_uri", AppsConfiguration.idaRedirect_uri));
            var client1 = new HttpClient();
            var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, AppsConfiguration.idaTokenEndpoint) { Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(keyValuePairs) };

            using (var res = client1.SendAsync(req).Result)
            {
                if (res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var jsonresult = JObject.Parse(await res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
                    token = (string)jsonresult["access_token"];
                    refresh_token = (string)jsonresult["refresh_token"];    
                }
            }

            return token;
        }
```

Do I need to do any specific configuration in the Azure AD V2 app?

Thank you!

Comment: If you use the oauth 2 for the native app, you should remove the client_secret.

Answer (score 0):

I was using login URL for v2 endpoint as : https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id={client id}....

Though this worked for Active Directory accounts and onmicrosoft accounts, it didn't worked for Microsoft Personal accounts like hotmail/outlook.

For me it worked when I changed the above login URL to :
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{domain name/tenand id}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id={client id}....

Thank you!